# sheaf cohomology of a divisor in a complex torus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

I want to compute few sheaf cohomology groups of sub tori of a complex tori and having some trouble doing it. Could any of you give suggestion on how to compute the cohomology groups? Those are what I want to compute

For 3 complex dimensional tori X, let D be a 2 complex dimensional tori, which is also a divisor in X. Then how could I compute
$$ H^{\bullet}(D,K_X)$$
where$ K_X$ is the canonical bundle of the 3 dimensional complex tori X.

For a question I asked, I first thought that I could perhaps use a short exact sequence
$$ 0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(-D)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_D\rightarrow 0 $$
by tensoring $ K_X$ to the short exact sequence. But then, I do not know the cohomology groups
$$ H^\bullet (X, \mathcal{O}_X(-D))$$
and
$$ H^\bullet (X, \mathcal{O}_X(-D)\otimes K_X)$$

Could you give me any suggestion regarding problem I have?

Thank you in advance

Comment: First, it is bad form to use $K_X$ for the normal bundle, since it is reserved for the canonical bundle of $X$. Second, I hope you realize that in your situation, the normal bundle is just $\mathcal{O}_D$.

Comment: Dear @Mohan thank you for your comment. normal bundle was a typo, what I meant was the canonical bundle.

Comment: The question is confusing to me. Do you know that the canonical bundles of $X$ and of $D$ are both trivial?

Comment: @bertram Yes, I know that tori admits trivial canonical bundle. But is $K_X$ restricted on D also trivial? Because I want to compute $ H^\bullet (D,K_X)$ not $ H^\bullet (X,K_X).$

Comment: @MankiKim If you have a trivial bundle, its restriction to any subset is trivial. For example, for line bundles a single global section with no zeroes trivializes $L$, and the restriction of the section to $D$ then trivializes $L|_D$. If you'd like a slogan to keep in mind, remember that "twistedness" can only decrease upon restriction; for example, the restriction of *any* bundle to an affine open is trivial.

Comment: Edit: I think that last clause should say "...to a sufficiently small affine open."